# Detect ranges of integers in a list in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write a function "detect_range" which detects ranges of integers from a list let's say:

---

```
a = [2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 12, 13]
```

---

```
import itertools
def detect_range(L):
    for i, j in itertools.groupby(enumerate(L), lambda x: x[1] - x[0]): 
        j = list(j) 
        yield j[0][1], j[-1][1] 
print(list(detect_range(a)))
```

---

It prints:

---

```
[(2, 2), (4, 8), (10, 10), (12, 13)]
```

---

However, I do not want the single integer like 2 and 10 to be printed in a pair, but single. So the output which I am looking from this code is:

---

```
[2, (4, 9), 10, (12, 14)]
```

Comment: The ``(4,8)`` in your 'is' example does not match the ``(4,9)`` in your 'should' example, but you don't mention that change anywhere. Please specify.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using itertools, you should add an if-statement to differenciate between the different cases.

To make the code more readable, I added the temporal variables `start` and `length`.

```
import itertools

def detect_range(L):
    for i, j in itertools.groupby(enumerate(L), lambda x: x[1] - x[0]):
        j = list(j)
        start = j[0][1]
        length = len(j)

        if length == 1:
            yield start
        else:
            yield (start, start+length)

print(list(detect_range(a)))
```

> [2, (4, 9), 10, (12, 14)]

---

Otherwise, you could scrap itertools and simply implement your own algorithm:

```py
def detect_range(input_list):
    start = None
    length = 0

    for elem in input_list:

        # First element
        if start is None:
            start = elem
            length = 1
            continue

        # Element in row, just count up
        if elem == start + length:
            length += 1
            continue

        # Otherwise, yield
        if length == 1:
            yield start
        else:
            yield (start, start+length)

        start = elem
        length = 1

    if length == 1:
        yield start
    else:
        yield (start, start+length)


print(list(detect_range(a)))
```

> [2, (4, 9), 10, (12, 14)]

Answer (score 0):

You can change the yield statement to have a condition -

```
def detect_range(L):
    for i, j in itertools.groupby(enumerate(L), lambda x: x[1] - x[0]): 
        j = list(j) 
        yield (j[0][1], j[-1][1]) if j[0][1]!=j[-1][1] else j[0][1]
```

Output:

```
[2, (4, 8), 10, (12, 13)]
```

Also the expected output is different from the given output (apart from single 2 and 10). So, this code assumes that it was a typo

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
 if j[0][1] == j[-1][1]:
     yield j[0][1]
 else:
     yield j[0][1], j[-1][1]
```